Can I see QScrollArea content outside the QScrollArea frame on the background of other widgets?
I have messenger-like QMainWindow class with 4 widgets on QVBoxLayout.
First,second and fourth - have transparent backgrounds.
Third widget is QScrollArea with dialog. And it works well, but I want to see dialog continuation over this QScrollArea, to see dialog on the background of other widgets (1,2,4) (on top and bottom).
I'm asking about other ideas how I could see QScrollArea content on the background of other widgets. Maybe someone encounter with it.
I tried to solve this and nothing works for me besides one variant: is to bring other widgets to the front using .raise_() function and QScrollArea remains the same (and fills all window background). But other problems appears:

Need to add padding at the top and bottom of dialog (because I can't scroll to first and last messages to see it not only on other widgets background). Also every time change these paddings if 1,2,4 widgets change their height.
I need to see scrolls of QScrollArea only in third widget place, not on the whole window. And I don't know how to do it.

My code:
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QScrollArea, QLabel
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scroll_area)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.scroll_area)
        self.main_layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        scroll_area_widget_contents = QWidget()
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_area_widget_contents)
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        scroll_layout = QVBoxLayout(scroll_area_widget_contents)
        scroll_layout.addWidget(QLabel(f"This message user can't read without padding (the message can't reach widget 3)"))
        for i in range(50):
            scroll_layout.addWidget(QLabel(f"Message {i+1}"))
        scroll_layout.addWidget(QLabel(f"This message user can't read without padding (the message can't reach widget 3)"))

        self.create_transparent_widget('Widget 1', 'background: rgba(50, 100, 50, 180);')
        self.create_transparent_widget('Widget 2', 'background: rgba(50, 100, 50, 180);')
        self.create_transparent_widget('Widget 3 (here we need to have horizontal and vertical scrolls of self.scroll_area)', 'background: rgba(0,0,0,0);')
        self.create_transparent_widget('Widget 4', 'background: rgba(50, 100, 50, 180);')

    def create_transparent_widget(self, widget_name, style):
        widget = QLabel(widget_name)
        widget.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        widget.setStyleSheet(style)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Result:


Painting can never happen outside the widget geometry, meaning that a child can never be shown "outside" of its parent. Despite the fact that a dialog should normally be a separate window, if you really want that to be shown as "embedded" in the window but outside of that scroll area, then it shouldn't be a child of that scroll area, but of the window itself. Please provide a [mre] based on your current implementation, then a screenshot of the actual result and possibly an image mockup of the wanted result.

I doubt this could be actually achieved with QScrollArea, and not even through QAbstractScrollArea. Setting a layout on the QScrollArea itself (not its contents) won't help you in any way, since it's not supposed to be used like that. The only option I can think of is to use a custom widget, with the scrollable contents set in a child widget that is not managed by the layout but manually resized in the resizeEvent(), and adding a dummy scroll bar in the third place, connected to a function that actually "scrolls" the contents. That's not impossible, but also not easy to achieve reliably.
